# How to save a post to a Custom post type and copy the information to another Custom post type?

Tags: php, functions

I used the Jet Engine plugin to create the first Custom Post Type called registration, the Post Type Slug called registration, and the Rewrite Slug called registration-add.

The first Custom Post Type called record has some meta fields called:

First Meta Field is:
Label: ENTRY Date
Name/ID: date-entry
Object type: Field
Field type: Date
Save as timestamp

The second Meta Field is:
Label: ENTRY TIME
Name/ID: hour-entry
Object type: Field
Field type: Time

The second Custom Post Type is called output_record, the Post Type Slug is called output_record, and the Rewrite Slug is called output-add-record.

The second Custom Post Type called output_register has some meta fields called:

First Meta Field is:
Label: ENTRY Date (EXIT RECORD)
Name/ID: date-entry-exit
Object type: Field
Field type: Date
Save as timestamp

The second Meta Field is:
Label: ENTRY TIME (EXIT RECORD)
Name/ID: hour-entry-exit
Object type: Field
Field type: Time

I am using a form plugin that publishes the post in the first Custom Post Type called record and that post is also saved in the Second Custom Post Type called record_output, you will wonder why, it is very simple it is a record where someone enters, and there must be a trace, but if it is going to leave, there must be another custom post type where the same information is that will later be edited to go from entering to leaving, that is, each post is an "entry and exit record". I just need that when it posts to that record custom post type it also posts to output.

Comment: This is something your form would need to do. You'll need to ask the plugin author how you can create two posts.

Comment: Very true I have looked for it but it only allows me to choose only 1 resource in the Save button, that is, a single post type, I should change the form... to save code, right?

Comment: The problem I have with the Jet Form Builder plugin is that the image preview when uploading looks 100x100 pxs and it is important that it looks at the size that I define. Everything else does fine. The plugin is free and is in the WordPress repository, I'll give you the link. https://wordpress.org/plugins/jetformbuilder/ @JacobPeattie